# Windows Deployment - Updating Litetouch to Windows 1903

Tags: windows, deployment, wds

I want to update the litetouch deployment to run as the 10.1.18362.1 version of Windows PE.

I have updated the ADK on the deployment server to 10.1.18362.1. It was previously on 10.1.17763.1.

When I go into Deployment Workbench, right click on the deployment share and then select the option to update the deployment share, choose "completely regenerate" it runs through the process. I can see that it has created a new WIM file from the timestamp, but when I import it into boot images in the Deployment Services console the version is still 10.1.17763.1.

What are the correct steps I need to perform to update the version so it matches the OS build I am wanting to install which is 1903?

Comment: PE is a separate download from the ADK, did you update the pe module?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get this to work. I needed to install the add-on as well and was then able to generate a boot image for the latest version.

Comment: Got ya, I'll write it as an answer then :)

Comment: No problem, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Overview

ADK and the PE files are now distributed as separate downloads. To be able to update the PE files, you will need to update the installed Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit's PE module to the latest version.

---

## How to fix

1. Download a new copy of the ADK PE module
   [image: Screenshot of the ADK installer download in Google Chrome]
2. Install The latest version of the PE Module
   [image: Screenshot of the Terms and Conditions page of the ADK PE module installer with Windows 10 visuals]
3. Rebuild the Deployment share using complete boot image rebuild option
   [image: Screenshot of the rebuild options for the deployment share]
4. Profit!
   [image: Screenshot of the WIM information after a MDT rebuild]

---

## tl;dr

PE is a seperate download from ADK; Update the PE module to get a newer MDT PE Image.

---

## Links

- ADK Home Page: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install
- Windows ADK 1903 Download: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086042
- Windows ADK 1903 PE Module: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2087112
- Hotfix for ADK 1903 SIM (fixes catalog generation bug): https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2095334